# Issue relate to RER in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, provider-hosted-app, remote-event-receiver, debugging, azure-service-bus

I am trying to create a Remote event receiver on SharePoint online. I followed steps given in the below url to create it :

[Steps to create a remote event receiver](https://www.sptechcon.com/blog/steps-to-create-a-remote-event-receiver-using-visual-studio-2015-for-sharepoint-online-and-deploy-into-microsoft-azure)

RER is getting deployed successfully but not getting triggered. I tried to debug it but I am getting below message

> One or more services were unregistered from the Microsoft Azure Service Bus.
>   Cannot register Services/AppEventReceiver.svc on Microsoft Azure Service Bus: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

I looked for the message and getting solution related to **Connection string** only. I have tried creating **Service Bus** from Azure UI and using Powershell both, but still not able to debug the solution.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What’s the type of connection string you used to connect to the Microsoft Azure Service Bus, ACS or SAS?

If you use ACS, it seems the Microsoft Azure Access Control Service (ACS) is restired, you can migrate to SAS refer to the article: 
[How to: Migrate from the Azure Access Control Service](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-acs-migration#clients-of-microsoft-cloud-services)

Or use the cloud explorer in Visual Studio and "attach debugger".

Reference: [Debugging an Azure cloud service or virtual machine in Visual Studio](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/azure/vs-azure-tools-debug-cloud-services-virtual-machines?view=vs-2019)

Or use a proxy.

Reference: [Remote Event Receivers – you’re all doing it wrong](https://derekgusoff.wordpress.com/2017/11/08/remote-event-receivers-youre-all-doing-it-wrong/)

Comment: In Azure I am not getting option of ACS or SAS for connection string. It is displaying Primary connection string and secondary connection string. I have tried using both of the connection strings but it's not working of any of them. I am using Azure free trial as of now. Is this can be the reason. Moreover I will try to other debug options.

Comment: It seems we can use Azure free trial. You can check the link to verify the process of configuring Azure service bus: https://blog.virtosoftware.com/remote-event-receivers-creating-and-debugging-sharepoint-online/

Comment: Seems like I am following the exact process. The only difference is ACS(in example) and Primary connection string(in my case). I have tried creating service bus from both UI and Power Shell. I am not able to understand where things going wrong. Since I am working with RER and Azure for the first time so don't have much idea about it.